# Como classificar o array multidimensional por valor?

Tags: php, laravel, lógica

Como posso classificar esse `array` pelo valor da chave **nivel**, mesmo que os valores sejam atualmente sequenciais, eles nem sempre serão?

```
array:67 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:8 [▼
      "idPai" => 1
      "id" => 93
      "nome" => "Pesoa"
      "nivel" => 2
      "email" => "email@gmail.com"
      "telefone" => "fone"
      "endereco" => "endereco"
      "imagem" => "uploads/avatars/1547216218.jpeg"
    ]
    1 => array:8 [▶]
    2 => array:8 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:8 [▼
      "idPai" => 93,
      "id" => 96,
      "nome" => "Pesoa",
      "nivel" => 2,
      "email" => "email@gmail.com",
      "telefone" => "fone",
      "endereco" => "endereco",
      "imagem" => "uploads/avatars/1547216218.jpeg"
    ]
    1 => array:8 [▶]
    2 => array:8 [▶]
  ] 
3 => array:3 [▶]
  4 => []
  5 => []
  6 => []
```

Eu gostaria primeiro, de filtrar esses registros e garantir que a sequencia de **niveis** seja seguida, exemplo, todos os **niveis 1**, depois todos os **niveis 2**, depois todos os **niveis 3** e assim vai.

Eu tentei

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b){
    if (count($a) > 0 and count($b) > 0) {
      return strcmp($a["nivel"], $b["nivel"]);
    }
});
```

Porém não funcionou, como eu posso fazer para ordenar baseado no valor do índice **nivel** esses caras?

O método que monta o array é esse

```
public function getMatrizRecursive($users = null, $nivel = 1)
{
$nivel++;

if ($nivel > 9) {
  return $this->matriz;
}

$montaArrayRede = [];

foreach ($users as $p){

  $children = User::where('id', '=', $p->posicao1)
  ->orWhere('id', '=', $p->posicao2)
  ->orWhere('id', '=', $p->posicao3)->get();

  foreach($children as $pessoa){
    $montaArrayRede[] = [
    'idPai' => $p->id,
    'id' => $pessoa->id,
    'nome' => $pessoa->nome,
    'nivel' => $nivel,
    'email' => $pessoa->email,
    'telefone' => $pessoa->telefone,
    'endereco' => $pessoa->cidade,
    'imagem' => $pessoa->logo_number
    ];
  }
  array_push($this->matriz, $montaArrayRede);

  $this->getMatrizRecursive($children, $nivel);
}

return $this->matriz;

 }
```

Observação: alguns índices retornam vazios.

Comment: Não seria mais pratico fazer isso na na busca ? Coloca o método que você está usando para gera esse array.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo editei a pergunta e adicionei o método, se olhar ele desce por todos os descendentes de um "children" até chegar no ultimo e depois volta para o "nível atual"